# Highcharts: how to highlight yAxis value?

Tags: javascript, html, css, charts, highcharts

I am trying to give highcharts yAxis values a simple highlight to at certain points. I have a value range that goes to 1 to 50, but I need to highlight 1, 30 and 50.

Is there a way to do that? (green)

my chart is bar right now but it could be column, I don`t mind

[image]

```js
      var cidades = ["São Paulo", "Rio de Janeiro", "Belo Horizonte", "Curitiba", "Salvador", "Fortaleza", "Florianópolis"] 
      var valoresCidades = [45, 35, 25, 15, 10, 5, 2];
       
          $('#chartCidades').highcharts({
              chart: {
                  type: 'bar'
              },
              title: {
                  text: 'Pedidos por região'
              },
              xAxis: {
                  categories: cidades
              },
              yAxis: {
                  min: 0,
                  max: 50,
                  title: {
                      text: 'Número de pedidos'
                  },
     plotLines: [{
      value: 50,
      color: 'green',
      dashStyle: 'shortdash',
      width: 2,
     }, {
      value: 30,
      color: 'grey',
      dashStyle: 'shortdash',
      width: 2,
     }],
                  stackLabels: {
                      enabled: true,
                      style: {
                          fontSize: '10',
                          fontWeight: 'lighter',
                          color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
                      }
                  }
              },
              legend: {
                  align: 'left',
                  x: -30,
                  verticalAlign: 'top',
                  y: 25,
                  floating: true,
                  backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || 'white',
                  borderColor: '#CCC',
                  borderWidth: 1,
                  shadow: false
              },
              tooltip: {
                  headerFormat: '<b>{point.x}</b><br/>',
                  pointFormat: '{series.name}: {point.y:,.0f}<br/>'
              },
              legend: {
                  y: 30,
                  verticalAlign: "top",
                  align: "center",
              },
              plotOptions: {
                  column: {
                      dataLabels: {
                          enabled: false,
                          color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white',
                          style: {
                              fontSize: '9',
                              textShadow: '0 0 1px black'
                          }
                      }
                  }
              },
              colors: [
                  '#FF5722',
                  '#607D8B'
              ],
              series: [{
                  name: 'Pedidos',
                  data: valoresCidades
              }]
          });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
   <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
   <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/map.js"></script> 
   <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<div id="chartCidades"></div>
```

Comment: Please paste your code :)

Comment: do you have a fiddle? or at least the code

Comment: Sorry. I've added a code snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens that you can add plotLines to the yAxis initialization options, like this:

```
                    plotLines: [{
                        value: 50,
                        color: 'green',
                        dashStyle: 'shortdash',
                        width: 2,
                    }, {
                        value: 30,
                        color: 'grey',
                        dashStyle: 'shortdash',
                        width: 2,
                    }],
```

This basically solved my problem. I have updated my original snippet.

Answer (score 1):

You can add plotLines or even areas to the chart to achieve that effect. (one or many). You can use addPlotLine to any axis.

http://jsfiddle.net/aev2u0a4/

```
 chart.yAxis[0].addPlotLine({
                value: 500,
                color: 'red',
                width: 2,
                id: 'plot-line-1'
            });
```

Here is a sample based on highcharts own demo. Click the button to see the line added/removed.

[hc API doc](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Axis.addPlotLine)